# Is logistic regression more free from the conditional independence assumption than naive Bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, naive-bayes

To my understanding, logistic regression is an extension of naive Bayes.

Suppose $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N \}$ and $Y = \{0, 1\}$, each $x_i$ is i.i.d and $P(x_i \mid Y=y_k) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a Gaussian distribution.

In order to create a *linear decision surface*, we take the assumption of each pdf $P(x_i \mid y_k)$ having variance $\sigma^2$ independent of the value of $Y$, i.e. 
$\sigma_{i, k} = \sigma_i$ ($i \rightarrow x_i, k \rightarrow y_k$).

Finally, we end up learning the coefficients $(\omega_0, \omega_i)$  that represent the *linear decision surface* in following equation (linear decision surface):

$$
\frac{P(Y=0 \mid X)}{P(Y=1 \mid X)} = \omega_0 + \sum_{i} \omega \cdot x_i
$$

Even though the derivation of Linear Regression coefficients$(\omega_0, \omega_i)$ involves the assumption of conditional independent $x_i$ given $Y$, *why is it said that learning these coefficients from training data are "somewhat more free" from conditional independence assumption, as compared to learning the regular Bayesian Distribution coefficients $\mu, \sigma$*?

I came across this while following [this course here](https://youtu.be/z_xPu9KrgCY?t=2008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer you to [Prof. Tom Mitchell](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/)'s (the lecturer in the video) [draft chapter](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/NBayesLogReg.pdf) as the best explanation I could find. I will try to explain it in layman's terms here.

Given a boolean problem, our logistic regression classifier will assign the label $Y=0$ iff $w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}X_{i} > 0$ (from the video you posted; eqn. 18 in the draft chapter). Otherwise, it will assign the label $Y=1$. Remember the goal of logistic regression is to learn the weights $w_0, w_1, ..., w_n$ that will give us a linear function that would seperate our data best.

It can be shown that $w_0=\ln\frac{1-\pi}{\pi} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\mu_{i1}^2 - \mu_{i0}^2}{2\sigma_{i}^2}$ and $w_i = \frac{\mu_{i0} - \mu_{i1}}{\sigma_{i}^2}$ (eqns. 19-23 in the draft chapter), where:

1. $\pi$ is $P(Y=1)$,
2. $\mu_{i0}$ and $\mu_{i1}$ are the means of feature $X_i$ in classes $Y=0$ and $Y=1$, respectively, and
3. $\sigma_i$ is the standard deviation of feature $X_i$

This means that we can express our weights $w_0, w_1, ..., w_n$ in terms of the Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier's parameters. Now, here is the difference:

Our goal is to find $P(Y=y_k|X_1 ... X_n)$. Assuming conditional independence, $P(Y=y_k|X_1 ... X_n) \propto P(Y=y_k) \prod_{i}^n P(X_i | Y=y_k)$.

*If we estimate $\pi$, $\mu_{i0}$, $\mu_{i1}$, and $\sigma_i$, then use those values to estimate $w_0, w_1, ..., w_n$, then we use the conditional independence property directly in our calculations.* This is what the Naive Bayes classifier does.

*If we estimate $w_0, w_1, ..., w_n$ directly, by repeatedly minimizing the error of an assumed linear function, we are not strictly abiding by the conditional independence property, because we don't explicitly calculate an estimate of the conditional probability $P(X_i|Y=y_k)$. We completely bypass that step.* This is what the Logistic Regression classifier does.

From the section 4 of the draft chapter (GNB is short for Gaussian Naive Bayes):

> ... Logistic Regression directly estimates the parameters of $P(Y|X)$, whereas Naive Bayes directly estimates parameters for $P(Y)$ and $P(X|Y)$... if the GNB assumptions hold, then asymptotically (as the number of training examples grows
>   toward infinity) the GNB and Logistic Regression converge toward identical classifiers.

Another way to understand this is that it has to do with the fact that **Logistic Regression is a discriminative classifier**, whereas **Naive Bayes is a generative classifier**. For more on that, read [Prof. Andrew Y. Ng](https://www.andrewng.org/) and [Prof. Michael I. Jordan](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/)'s paper, *[On Discriminative vs. Generative classifiers: A comparison of logistic regression and naive Bayes](https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-discriminativegenerative.pdf)*.